# What tool/method should I use to clean up this laminate edge?

Tags: countertops, laminate

I just built my first laminate countertop yesterday and finished routing all the edges. Almost halfway through routing, my bit broke so I had to borrow  a beveled trim router bit. This bit left a mess with the backer from the top sheet[image] exposed on the top edge as shown in the picture.
What should I use to clean up this edge, since all the laminate is on the surfaces now? Can I use a certain grit of sandpaper without damaging the laminate? Or is there a file that is fine enough? I am concerned because I will be scraping that residue off of the edge with the new laminate. It has the texture of cardboard, I think it's just the laminate backer.
Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I would invest in a new laminate routing bit and go over that edge.  You could also a chisel and lightly score the edges. I'd put some masking tape on the laminate to protect it while your finishing the edges. A fine grit sandpaper would also work.

Comment: Totally agree with JACK.  Just buy a high quality laminate trimming bit, (beveled or straight, your choice) and go over it again. There should be no cleanup needed afterwards other than maybe  a very light sanding to soften up the edges (220 or 400 grit), very light. +

Comment: Masking tape on laminate may be applied before sanding.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a fine job for a razor scraper.

[image]

If not then a super sharp wood chisel would also work.

If using either tool you should be careful to not let the tool dig into the laminate. Make sure it's only slicing out the unwanted material.

Other thought: can you re-route it with a higher quality bit which won't leave behind such a mess?

Comment: All good thoughts, I'll let on a secret... This was my first time using a router. So would it do any harm going over the same edge with a trim router? I want to ensure the cutting blade wouldn't gouge the side.

Comment: @BigLake I don't have enough experience to offer any advice on your idea. It seems like [JACK's answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/224525/42053) offers advice though. You would be better off commenting on their answer.